# add a DOM object to array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```js
a_ajouter = $('.question');
hidden_div.push(a_ajouter);

console.log(hidden_div);
```

Well, a DOM object should be added to the div, however, the console shows 'jQuery.fn.init[1](http://gazouz.hol.es/tests/tp1.html)' as the its last element. No idea what this is.

Here is [the page itself](http://gazouz.hol.es/tests/tp1.html). If i was not clear enought (click on the arrow to start event)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a jQuery array inside your normal array,
what you want is to add the jQuery object.

```
a_ajouter = $('.question').eq(0); //first element
hidden_div.push(a_ajouter);
console.log(hidden_div);
```

or the DOM object itself.

```
a_ajouter = $('.question').eq(0); //first element
hidden_div.push(a_ajouter[0]); //html element without the jquery wrapper
console.log(hidden_div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast jQuery object to DOM object, you should use `get()`, for example `$('.question').get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `a_ajouter` is a jQuery object, if you want to insert all the elements in the jQuery object to an existing array you can try

```
a_ajouter = $('.question');
hidden_div.push.apply(hidden_div, a_ajouter.get());
console.log(hidden_div);
```

If you want to have a new array then you can use `a_ajouter.get()` like

```
hidden_div =  a_ajouter.get();
```